# :First-child affecting all children

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Hi I'm trying to target the first `<a>` element under .current-cat-parent but my jquery code is affecting all the `<a>` elements underneath this. How can I just target the first immediate `<a>` element? Thanks!

```
$(".current-cat-parent a:first-child").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
          if( $(this).hasClass('hide') ){
            $(this).next().slideDown(800);
            $(this).removeClass('hide');
          } else { 
            $(this).next().slideUp(800);
            $(this).addClass('hide');
          }
    });
```

```html
<li class="cat-item cat-item-1 current-cat-parent">
  <a title="View all posts filed under Clothing" href="http://site.com/category/clothing">Clothing</a>
  <ul class="children">
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-3"><a title="View all posts filed under Jeans" href="http://site.com/category/clothing/jeans">Jeans</a></li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-2 current-cat"><a title="View all posts filed under Suits" href="http://site.com/category/clothing/suits">Suits</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: The anchors are all first children within their context? -> `$(".current-cat-parent a:first")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to target the *first* child.

```
$(".current-cat-parent a:eq(0)")
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this:

```
$(".current-cat-parent a:first-child")
```

use the direct child `>`:

```
$(".current-cat-parent > a:first-child")
```

### Note:

I think your main issue is `.hide` css class. Why you need it? I suggest you to make it a blank css class or remove it.

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hYMWf/)

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
$(".current-cat-parent a:eq(0)").click(function(e){
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the HTML markup closely, you will notice that all `a` elements are also `first-child` of their respective parents. The solution is to use one of these selectors:

```
.current-cat-parent > a
.current-cat-parent a:first
.current-cat-parent a:eq(0)
```

Note that `:first` and `:first-child` are not the same.